# Intellij abnormal build process termination

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nvidia, java-8

So, I just updated my NVIDIA graphics driver (GeForce game ready driver) to 378.49, and now when I try to build any Java project, I get this error:

> Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dpreload.project.path=C:/Users/Displee/Documents/Private/Webserver -Dpreload.config.path=C:/Users/Displee/.IntelliJIdea2016.3/config/options -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=5407721408972744302 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Djps.file.types.component.name=FileTypeManager -Duser.language=nl -Duser.country=NL -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2016.3 "-Didea.home.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3" -Didea.config.path=C:\Users\Displee.IntelliJIdea2016.3\config -Didea.plugins.path=C:\Users\Displee.IntelliJIdea2016.3\config\plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/Displee/.IntelliJIdea2016.3/system/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/jre" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=1.8.0_101 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/Displee/.IntelliJIdea2016.3/system/compile-server/*temp* -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.experimental=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\Displee\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-5596753944155912704-is-running\" -classpath "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/protobuf-2.5.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/rt/jps-plugin-system.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/jdom.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/jna.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/jna-platform.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/netty-all-4.1.5.Final.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/log4j.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/oromatcher.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/trove4j.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/openapi.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/snappy-in-java-0.5.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/jgoodies-forms.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/asm-all.jar;;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-groovy-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-cli-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-core-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-logging-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-messaging-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-core-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-groovy-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-native-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-process-services-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-resources-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-api-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-impl.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-wrapper-3.1.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/kryo-2.22.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/minlog-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-amd64-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-i386-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-amd64-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-i386-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-amd64-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-i386-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-amd64-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-i386-0.11.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/reflectasm-1.07.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/lib/gson-2.5.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/ui-designer-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/common-eclipse-util.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/maven/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/maven/lib/aether-1.1.0-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/maven/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/maven/lib/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/osmorc/lib/osmorc-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/osmorc/lib/bndlib-3.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/osmorc/lib/bnd-repository-3.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/osmorc/lib/bnd-resolve-3.3.0.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/osmorc/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.10.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/osmorc/lib/bundlor-all.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/aspectj/lib/aspectj-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/flex/lib/flex-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/flex/lib/flex-shared.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/JavaEE/lib/javaee-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jps/jpa-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/webSphereIntegration/lib/jps/webSphere-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/weblogicIntegration/lib/jps/weblogic-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/dmServer/lib/dmServer-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/GwtStudio/lib/gwt-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/GoogleAppEngine/lib/google-app-engine-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/GoogleAppEngine/lib/appEngine-runtime.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/Grails/lib/grails-compiler-patch.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-gradle-jps.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/android/lib/sdk-common.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/android/lib/repository.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/android/lib/sdklib.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/android/lib/common.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/android/lib/layoutlib-api.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/android/lib/manifest-merger.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-compiler-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX-plugin.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 51505 e8c185c4-27ca-4e7f-ad66-3b2991449e79 C:/Users/Displee/.IntelliJIdea2016.3/system/compile-server

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by downgrading my nvidia driver (Devicemanager -> Display adapters -> nvidia GeForce driver -> right click properties -> driver tab -> previous driver).